# Design pattern behind modularization?

Tags: design-patterns, modularity

Hi I'm writing my own high level API of Amazon's PHP SDK which is used to manipulate DynamoDB, a nosql database.

I find myself writing roughly 150 lines of code for a single function that does one operation, including error checking, request building and of course, comments. If I keep going this way the API class can easily exceed a thousand lines, which I think is a bit hard to maintain.

Thus I'm thinking of breaking my class down into several smaller classes, each handling a set of operations. Say like, table operations, item operations, and batch operations. But I'm not an expert with software design patterns, so is this really a good way to modularize? Or is there any design pattern that I should comply and make my code easier to maintain?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to modularize your program by writing classes that handle specific tasks. Design patterns is a more advanced issue that facilitates code reusing and integration. So you should take it carefully according to your software architecture. You can read more about it here: www.oodesign.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit subjective, since you do not provide the code so that we can see what you're trying to accomplish in fact.

But yes, you need to **separate your classes into smaller components**, each one with its own responsibility. There isn't a single pattern that tells how exactly to do that, but the [**Single Responsibility Principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is a good one to start with. It's about [**separation of concerns**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

You said:

> [...] including error checking, request building [...]

There you go, separating **error checking**, from **request building**, and then separating it again into smaller components, each with just one responsibility. You must have **just one reason to change** each component, never more then one. You must have a clear **domain model** defined, with dedicated services for each one of these domain objects.

Take for example, the answer of @teresko here:

[How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc)

So, bear in mind that you need to [separate your application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Comparison_with_the_MVC_architecture) into **layers**. The request is part of the **presentation tier**. Which in modern [MVC-alike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) apllications is composed by the Controller Layer and the View Layer, which interacts with the Model layer in order to prepare the presentation for a given request.

See: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I already have a class for checking errors, but there are still 20+ lines of code for each function to invoke the appropriate error checking method, since there are just a lot of parameters (6~8). And for comments... Probably no one is responsible for the comments here LOL.

Comment: That MVC question you provided looks very interesting, and the answer is very helpful, I read a bit but not all yet... Will definitely read it through when I have time. It really helped me see the big picture clearer now.

Comment: I think how I separate my class somehow depends on how I can factor out the similar codes in each function here.

Comment: Uh!? You may be better with exception handlers in order to treat each of the possible type of errors. What do you mean by `no one is responsible for the comments here`?

Comment: Oh by comments I meant the comments I inserted in between lines for human reader, not functional statements haha. So there is no need to separate them I think. :D

Comment: Ah! I thought it was a comments entity. Ops! :) Btw, make sure you're using exceptions correctly.

Comment: And after reading your answer, I realize that it may not be a good way to simply separate the class based on the database operations, but based on different layers of process that each function does. For example request building. Good that I learn something today :)

Comment: Just updated the answer with a few more infos... good luck with your researches.

Answer (score 2):

I think I am in the same boat as you.  I have lots of classes to maintain that have too many purposes.  Have a look at the following web page, which helped me: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx.  Also Google: SOLID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).  These are targeted towards .NET and Object Oriented programming, but I know that PHP has classes and objects.

Comment: Thanks for providing me the article, it certainly looks helpful, will read through it sometime. :D